# Jackson - JsonMappingException due to constructor

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am having the following exception when trying to deserialize a JSON

> No suitable constructor found for type `[simple type, class MyObj$obj$Card]:` can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at `[Source: java.io.StringReader@4344ee21; line: 1, column: 201]` (through reference chain: `MyObj["obj"]->Obj["cards"]`)

And the JSON is

```
{
  "obj":{
  "api":"OK",
  "cache":false,
  "cards":[
     {
        "id":1232995897,
        "items":[
           {
              "id":"vmdSJLpnY",
              "cat":50,
              "rating":0.0
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "id":0005897,
        "items":[
           {
              "id":"vxdSJLpnY",
              "cat":50,
              "rating":0.0
           }
        ]
     }
 ]
 }
}
```

And within the `Obj` class I have the following statement

`@JsonProperty("cards") private Card[] cards;`

Which produces the exception above. Changing the type `Card[]` to `Object[]` does not produce an exception, but it lacks of the correct mapping I desire to get.

Any clue how can I resolve it? A snippet will be GREAT!
What this error means anyhow?

**UPDATE**

I have included the Java class.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public final class MyObj {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
    public final class Obj {
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
        public final class Card {
            @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
            public final class Item {
                @JsonProperty("id") private String id;
                @JsonProperty("cat") private String cat;
                @JsonProperty("rating") private String rating;
                public final String getId() { return id; }
                public final String getCat() { return cat; }
                public final String getRating() { return ranting; }
                public final String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }
            }

            @JsonProperty("items") private Item[] items;
            public final Item[] getItems() { return items; }
            public final String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }
        }

        @JsonProperty("cards") private Card[] cards;
        public Card[] getCards() { return cards; }
        public final String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }      
    }


    @JsonProperty("obj") MyObj obj;
    public final Card[] getCards(){ return apiServiceResultsNoLists.getCards(); }
}
```

Comment: Please show java class which will be used for object mapper.

Comment: If you use the exact structure above, the error is due to the fact that jackson can not deserialize to inner classes. If you define them as static the problem should be solved

Comment: Hi Eugen,  your commetn qualifies as answer  but can not be accepted and upvoted as such

Comment: @eugen, i have changed the `Obj`, `Card` classes to static, and i still receive the same error. anyhow, i was able to instantiate inner classes which does not include array. **it is the array that causes all the problem**

Comment: Update your code with exactly what you have please, it would help us to solve the problem. All the inner classes must be static.

Answer (score 45):

I think the problem is most likely with the **Card** object

- it might not have a **default constructor**
- if it doesn't have a default constructor, it should be annotated using **[@JsonCreator](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html)**

**EDIT**
I have two things:
  * you don't have setters.
  * you don't have a public constructor that would be allowed to set your fileds.

How should the deserializer populate your fields if you don't give it any (legal*) means for it?

Solutions:
 -> add public setters to the classes
 -> or create parametrized constructors annotated with @JsonCreator

*: of course, the parser could do the reflective "mofidy the visibility" trick, but come on, this is not "the way it's meant to be played"

**EDIT2**
I think this should work, but I can't test it - I don't have a project at hand with Jackson properly set up now (this is just a part of it, but I think it is easy to interpret what I wanted to show.) Note, I changed the array to a List:

```
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)     
public final class Card {     
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

    public final class Item {     
        @JsonProperty("id") private String id;     
        @JsonProperty("cat") private String cat;     
        @JsonProperty("rating") private String rating;     

        @JsonCreator
        public Item(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("cat") String cat, @JsonProperty("rating") String rating) {
            this.id = id;
            this.cat = cat;
            this.rating = rating;
        }   


        public final String getId() { return id; }     
        public final String getCat() { return cat; }     
        public final String getRating() { return ranting; }     
        public final String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }     
    }     
    @JsonProperty("items") private List<Item> items;     

    @JsonCreator
    public Card(@JsonProperty("items") List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }       

    public final List<Item> getItems() { return items; }     

    public final String toString() { return new Gson().toJson(this); }     
}
```

Comment: See my answer to Konstantin Pribluda

Comment: This is not entirely true. (I mean that the def. constructor always exists...) Not, if you have specified another constructor, that has a parameter. In that case, the default constructor does not exist. (Note: I added my answer before you edited the question to show the code...)

Comment: I am using ` @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)` so when there is no explicit mapping using `@JsonProperty` it will be ignored. when using the `JsonProperty` for mapping, there is no need to use this annotation for accessors (getters\setters).

Comment: I do not seem to be able to produce your solution correctly. Could you please include a small snippet?

Comment: @MrRoth (reply to the comment preceding the last one) I see that. But the JSON parser is not in "God mode", so it will not be able to populate your fields: 1, they are private. 2, there are no public setters for them. 3, there is no constructor that would allow setting them at object creation time. **How should the parser set their values?**

Comment: @ppterka, please (!) provide a snippet.

Comment: @MrRoth I was busy doing so :) Sadly, I can't see if it works, I don't currently have a project set up to try...

Comment: I get different exception `Unrecognized Type: [null]`. **:(**

Comment: I think in this case, [@JsonDeserialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html) and [@JsonSerialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.2.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html) should be used, with  [CollectionDeserializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.1.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/deser/CollectionDeserializer.html) and [CollectionSerializer](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ser/ContainerSerializers.CollectionSerializer.html) class specified accordingly...

Comment: This does not works for but declaring inner class as static does

Answer (score 11):

I had the same symptoms the other day and took the advice about `JsonCreator` and `JsonProperty` but I got the same exact error message.  It turns out that the project I'm working on is using fasterxml's and codehaus' versions of jackson.  I put the codehaus attributes on my class but used fasterxml's ObjectMapper to do the parsing.  They joy of transitive dependencies.

Comment: Upvoted this. Read all documentation, but jackson was still expecting a default constructor. Was going crazy reading docs for jsonproperty and jsoncreator, until i realized the objectmapper class was the codehaus version. And the annotations were the fasterxml version. I made everything the fasterxml version and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

I have been facing same kind of problem. My Json data set is like following

```
{
"count": 1917,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "generated_id": "Z1-1156",
      "first_name": "Maruf",
      "last_name": "Ahmed",
      "full_name": "Mr. Maruf Ahmed",
      "email": "maruf1990@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+8801676798306",
      "company_name": "S M Style Ltd.",
      "website": "http:\\/\\/smartex-bd.com\\/",
      "address": "\\\nRoad No:5 House No:18\\\nLevel:3\\\nLane:\\\nBlock:F\\\nSector:2\\\nArea:Mirpur\\\nDhaka 1216\\\nMirpur\\\nBangladesh",
      "industry_type": "Apparel Retailer",
      "job_title": "Designer",
      "department": "Research & Development",
      "date": "7\\/10\\/2015 1:04:43 PM"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "generated_id": "Z2-1157",
      "first_name": "Akramul",
      "last_name": "Hoque",
      "full_name": "Mr. Akramul Hoque",
      "email": "akram@nassagroup.org",
      "phone": "+8801732005564",
      "company_name": "Nassa Group",
      "website": "www,nassagroup.org",
      "address": "Nassa Group\\\nRoad No:238 House No:\\\nLevel:\\\nLane:\\\nBlock:\\\nSector:\\\nArea:Gulshan li\\\nDhaka 1208\\\nTejgaon Industrial Area\\\nBangladesh",
      "industry_type": "Denim Garments Manufacturer",
      "job_title": "Merchandiser (Senior)",
      "department": "Merchandising",
      "date": "7\\/9\\/2015 10:56:22 PM"
    }
    ]
}
```

```
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Visitors {



      @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
      public static class Visitor{
        @JsonProperty("id")
        public String mId;

        @JsonProperty("generated_id")
        public String mGenId;

        @JsonProperty("first_name")
        public String mFirstName;

        @JsonProperty("last_name")
        public String mLastName;

        @JsonProperty("full_name")
        public String mFullName;

        @JsonProperty("email")
        public String mEmail;

        @JsonProperty("phone")
        public String mPhone;

        @JsonProperty("company_name")
        public String mCompanyName;

        @JsonProperty("website")
        public String mWebsite;

        @JsonProperty("address")
        public String mAdress;

        @JsonProperty("industry_type")
        public String mIndustryType;

        @JsonProperty("job_title")
        public String mJobtitle;

        @JsonProperty("department")
        public String mDepartment;

        @JsonProperty("date")
        public String mDate;


        public Visitor(@JsonProperty("id") String  Id,
                       @JsonProperty("generated_id") String  GenId,
                       @JsonProperty("first_name") String  FirstName,
                       @JsonProperty("last_name") String  LastName,
                       @JsonProperty("full_name") String  FullName,
                       @JsonProperty("email") String  Email,
                       @JsonProperty("phone") String  Phone,
                       @JsonProperty("company_name") String  CompanyName,
                       @JsonProperty("website") String  Website,
                       @JsonProperty("address") String  Adress,
                       @JsonProperty("industry_type") String  IndustryType,
                       @JsonProperty("job_title") String  Jobtitle,
                       @JsonProperty("department") String  Department,
                       @JsonProperty("date") String  date)
        {
          mId = Id;
          mGenId = GenId;
          mFirstName = FirstName;
          mLastName= LastName;
          mFullName= FullName;
          mEmail= Email;
          mPhone= Phone;
          mCompanyName= CompanyName;
          mWebsite= Website;
          mAdress= Adress;
          mIndustryType= IndustryType;
          mJobtitle= Jobtitle;
          mDepartment= Department;
          mDate= date;
        }
      }


      @JsonProperty("count") public String mCount;


      @JsonProperty("data")  public ArrayList<Visitor> mVisitorList;

      @JsonCreator
      public Visitors(  @JsonProperty("count") String Count,
                        @JsonProperty("data") ArrayList<Visitor> visitorList)
      {
        mCount = Count;
        mVisitorList = visitorList;
      }
    }
```

The issue was the inner class declaration, it should be static. Because jackson need to access it like

```
new Visitors.Visitor();
```

so i declared the inner `Visitor` class as `static`. It worked for me.

Comment: Inner class needing to be static resolved my issue. Did not require the @JsonCreator.

Comment: Thanks. making my inner class static too worked for me. But i need to know instead op making it static, if we create a new class & get has-a relationship will that work?

Comment: how you will specify the has a relationship, will you share bit of code to create the has a relationship ? @ShabbirEssaji

Answer (score 3):

I think your are missing default constructor in one of the classes.
Alternatively: add @JsonCreator annotation to the constructors

Comment: Could you please provide a small snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Look into your Card class -  most probably there is no accessible default constructor or constructor lacks proper mappings.

Comment: Default constructor exists by default. Hence its name. Even including it explicitly does not resolve the issue. Could you please post a small snippet for "proper mapping"?

Comment: It exists but is not necessarily accessible. As eugen points,  you will need to make this inner classes static ( as there is implicitc constructor parameter with type of enclosing class )

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda Yep exactly. Indeed when you use introspection on inner classes you see that there is an additional parameter at position 0 that corresponds to an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

Add default constructor to the class and all the nested user defined class. It should work then.