# JSON.decodeValue Decode Exception

Tags: java, json

I want to make this java code works:

```
RequestManager rm = Json.decodeValue(request.getBodyAsString(), RequestManager.class);
```

But i have this error:

`io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class RequestManager]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {"messageId":"fsdfsdf"}; line: 1, column: 2]`

And here the code of my class :

```
public class RequestManager {
    private String messageId;
    private String messageContent;

    public RequestManager(String messageId, String messageContent) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }
}
```

I really don't know why it's not working and there is only few topics about it, but they were irrelevant.

Someone can help ?

EDIT--

I know  have the RequestManager class like this:

```
public class RequestManager {
    private String messageId;
    private String messageContent;

    public RequestManager(String messageId, String messageContent) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.messageContent = messageContent + "check";
    }

    public RequestManager() {

    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageContent(String messageContent) {
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
    }
}
```

But know when i try to print the fields of my `RequestManager` object created with the `JSON.decodeValue` it's return me null. I've already done that in the past and had the same error. I think it's because the empty constructor is used instead.
I still don't really understand....

EDIT--2

I have tried to change my class again, here it is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class RequestManager {
    @JsonProperty("messageId") private String messageId;
    @JsonProperty("messageContent") private String messageContent;

    @JsonCreator
    public RequestManager(@JsonProperty("messageId") String messageId, @JsonProperty("messageContent") String messageContent) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
        System.out.println("This constructor is used.");
    }

    public RequestManager() {

    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageContent(String messageContent) {
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
    }
}
```

And this is in my main :
   `final RequestManager rm = Json.decodeValue("{\"messageId\":\"themessage\"}", RequestManager.class);
            System.out.println(rm.getMessageContent());`

`"{\"messageId\":\"themessage\"}"` = the JSON format, i'm sure of it because decodeValue would return a Decode Exception if it wasn't.

Now the field is "nullcheck" when i print it. So it means that the constructor is well used but the fields are nulls. Where am i doint it wrong ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835911/jackson-jsonmappingexception-due-to-constructor

Answer (score 1):

You could try to have an empty constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have your own constructor, and JSON doesn't know what values should be passed into it.

There is documentation on their GitHub page explaining how to set up a data object that you expect to be given to you as JSON and converted to Java.

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-codegen#data-objects

As per the example that you linked to: http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/, notice how they explicitly provide a constructor that takes no arguments, and public setter methods

```
Whisky()
setName(String name)
setOrigin(String origin)
```

The alternative is to provide annotations: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations. You can choose how to do it, using annotation if you want, or using a *bean* class (getters and setters). Annotation has the advantage that you can say things like "ignore this value when you convert to JSON", etc. You can be more explicit with annotation. *I would recommend picking one and staying with it. Consistency becomes important as your projects grow.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my code is strongly inspired from this one, http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/ and i don't see any use of a anoted class. Is this a bad exemple ?

Comment: i see i will try to use the annotation as well but i've never used it.