# How to get Jackson to ignore constructorproperties

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I'm trying to get Jackson to deserialize

```
{
    "test": 2018
}
```

to

```
SomeJavaClass:
 private final Test test
```

But I want to make my Test class using Project Lombok. However Lombok annotates the class with ConstructorProperties, and for some reason this makes jackson fail.

My classes looks like this:

```
@Value
public class SomeJavaClass {
    Test test;
}


@Value
public class Test{
    String value;
}
```

Test is delomboked as:

```
public class Test {
    int value;

    @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"value"})
    public Test(final int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Test)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Test other = (Test) o;
        if (this.getValue() != other.getValue()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        result = result * PRIME + this.getValue();
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Test(value=" + this.getValue() + ")";
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make Jackson ignore the constructorproperties somehow?

Comment: does @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) work for you? or this answer to a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835911/jackson-jsonmappingexception-due-to-constructor

Comment: Please add the full source code including all Lombok annotations.

Comment: There's an issue on GitHub about this problem: https://github.com/meltmedia/jackson-crypto/issues/6

Comment: So what is the error, how does it make Jackson to fail? What annotations you use? `@AllArgsConstructor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also think that the problem here is not the annotation `@java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"value"})`.

Based on your delombok it seems that you have a set of annotations that will prevent default constructor to form.

So maybe you get rid of this problem by adding `@NoArgsConstructor`. Without default constructor and having no `@JsonCreator`s you will have an error like:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of org.example.spring.jackson.JacksonTest$TestClass
>   (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object
>   value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this fails is not the `@ConstructorProperties`. In fact, this annotation is *required* to make Jackson work with Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor`.

The problem here is that the value of `test` in your JSON is an integer, but your class structure requires it to be an object. So you have to make the field `test` in `SomeJavaClass` an `int`. Then you also don't need the `Test` class. (Or rename `value` to `test` in `Test` and get rid of `SomeJavaClass` and deserialize to `Test`.)